# Starting Second of Two Loaders on Up Button Pressed

Tags: android, loader

I have two Loaders;

- Loader1 is an ArrayList Loader that populates data from the web.
- Loader2 is a Cursor Loader that converts a Cursor into an ArrayList on onLoadFinished, backed up by a local database.

The results are displayed in the same RecyclerView list. A spinner controls which results the user sees, and they can click an image to go to a 'detail' activity.

When I press Up on Activity B (detail) Loader1 is *always* called on onResume and there is seemingly nothing I can do to stop it. This means it will always show Loader1 data, even if the user clicked into detail from Loader2.

How can I prevent the auto calling of Loader1 on Up button pressed and subsequently choose whether to refresh Loader1 or Loader2 depending on the spinner status?

Comment: Can you not call Loader1 in the onCreateView method?

Comment: Hi, the problem is navigating from Activity B (detail) to Activity A will always call Loader1 in onResume in Activity A, even if I want it to call Loader2.

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: https://github.com/Tzar2nd/PopularMovies

Comment: Which activities? Generally you should share only the code in question on here for future reference.

Comment: LibraryActivity is the main Activity with the two Loaders and MovieDetailActivity is the detail activity. I'm finding it impossible to start Loader2 instead of Loader1 on returning from detail activity.